# GRUB load error

Tags: grub2

When I try installing Ubuntu from the Try Ubuntu off of my usb I get the error "executing 'grub-install/dev/sdb' failed". I had PCLinuxOS installed and I was attempting to fully replace it with Ubuntu 12.04 I've seen a lot of other questions similar to this but as far as I've been able to figure out none of the solutions work for me. when I run 
sudo fdisk -l in the terminal it shows that dev/sda1 is linux, dev/sda2 is extended, and 
div/sda5 is Linux swap/ Solaris then there is a dev/sdb1 that is FAT16

Sorry I couldn't figure out how to insert a screen shot but if needed and you can explain how I can post it.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the error "executing 'grub-install/dev/sdb' failed".

The installer is tying to install the Grub file on a USB flash drive or other external drive. `sda` is your internal drive. `sdb` is an external(I would suspect as it is formatted as FAT16 it is a flashdrive)

If the installer did the whole installation(takes about 20 minutes) but then failed at with only that error, Ubuntu should be installed.  You can install the Grub boot-loader by booting into the live USB and then doing the following.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Launch Boot Repair Using the Unity Dash: press Windows(Super) Key and start typing **"boot repair"** and click on the icon to open the program and the following box will open:

[image]

Click on the **Recommended Repair** the program should do the rest and install the Grub boot-loader to the correct disk **(sda)**<--Note it goes on the main disk not any of your partitions)

After Boot-Repair completes the repair you should be able to reboot you computer and then it will either load your new Ubuntu installation or Your old PCLinux, if for some reason Ubuntu didn't install.  **Note** The **Boot Repair** program will only be installed inside your live session, not your hard disk installation, if you want it permanently installed you will need to repeat the  installation instructions. (just to clarify, the repairs are permanent but the Boot Repair program itself is not)

If for some reason none of this works and you just want to reinstall Ubuntu, I would recommend downloading and burning a CD(or DVD) they don't tend to have these problems.

If you have any questions, see this page on the **Boot Repair** program

it is also my **Source:**  [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)